# php mail() on IIS6 not sending

Tags: iis-6, smtp, php5

**This is related to an IIS server problem, or a PHP configuration, *not php code*.**

I'm running an IIS6 server with PHP installed on it, the following php code will never send an email:

`mail("user@example.com", "hi",  "thanks");` //...mail(address, subject, message)

The server this is running under has a valid SMTP server, I know because I can telnet to **localhost:25** and send emails by directly talking to the protocol, so that's not an issue.

However, this code won't send. I've looked at my **php.ini** file, and it looks like it's all correct to me also:

```
[mail function]
SMTP = localhost
smtp_port = 25
```

**edit:**
I can confirm that programming that speaks to the socket with the SMTP protocol also works, but the mail() function still refuses.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Authentication in your php.ini file then you need to use SMTP authenticate Scripts to send out the mail from the server.

Answer (score 0):

check to see if you smtp service is running on the server.

easiest way is to open a command window, start -> run -> cmd

`telnet localhost 25`

see if you get any response, if not you need to start your smtp service.

Comment: I mentioned I could telnet into the service in my question.